# inner joins producing erroneous results for no clear reason

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am getting **strange** results from inner joins.  Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT  cm.PersonID
FROM dbo.vwCommitteeMembers cm

-- first join
INNER JOIN dbo.vwCommitteeTerms ct 
      ON (ct.CommitteeID = cm.CommitteeID)

-- second join
INNER JOIN dbo.vwCommitteeTermMembers ctm 
      ON (ct.ID = ctm.CommitteeTermID)

WHERE cm.CommitteeID = 124
```

If I comment out both joins, I get 24 results.  If I uncomment out the first join (leaving second commented out), I also get 24 results.  If, however, both joins are uncommented, the results are inflating to 576.  Since **24^2 = 576**, I have some idea what is happening, but I don't know why.  I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008, on a Windows 7 Pro x64 workstation, for a SQL Server 2008 database.  It "feels" like SSMS is trying to optimize my query somehow, but I really want to know what the root cause is so I don't have this problem in the future (as this is not the first time I've encountered it).  I even had a colleague take a look since I assumed I was just "too close" to the problem, and they thought it looked okay, too.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an erroneous result. You simply have multiple Members for a comittee term

Comment: if that is the case, then why am i still getting back 24 with just the first join?

Comment: Because the second join is the one with the table with members for a term comittee. You should add a join condition there with *probably* `cm.MemberId = ctm.MemberId` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamak's second comment was correct.  Expected results are produced when the query is modified to:

```
SELECT  cm.PersonID
FROM dbo.vwCommitteeMembers cm

-- first join
INNER JOIN dbo.vwCommitteeTerms ct 
      ON (ct.CommitteeID = cm.CommitteeID)

-- second join
INNER JOIN dbo.vwCommitteeTermMembers ctm 
      ON (ct.ID = ctm.CommitteeTermID AND ctm.MemberID = cm.PersonID)

WHERE cm.CommitteeID = 124
```